# What is procedure to print multiple envelopes with different addresses in Pages?

Tags: pages, printing, macos

I need to print a bunch of envelopes for holiday cards. How do I do this? I want to do it from Pages because I need to change some details on some before they print. How do I do this?

I am not seeing any easy or intuitive way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: They're never gonna get there in time, now ;-)

Comment: You've never met my mailman! 